# Method of undetermined coefficients is a little fuzzy

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone please remind me how to solve the following ODE

$$-4\frac{dv}{dx}-4\pi^2v(x)=\frac{1}{10}\sin(\pi x)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Find the **general** solution of the associated *homogenous* equation (that is, the equation we get when we replace $\frac{1}{10}\sin(\pi x)$ by $0$.)

You may be able to write down the general solution of the homogeneous equation immediately. It may help  to rewrite the equation as $\frac{dv}{dx}=-\pi^2 v$. What functions have derivative equal to a constant times themselves?

2) Find a **particular** solution of the original equation. (We address that later.)

3) Add.

**A particular solution:** Look for a solution $v(x)$ of the shape 
$$v(x)=A\cos(\pi x)+B\sin(\pi x).$$
 We want to find $A$ and $B$ that work.

Note that for this choice of $v$, we have
$$\frac{dv}{dx}=-\pi A \sin(\pi x)+\pi B \cos(\pi x).$$
Substitute $\frac{dv}{dx}$, $v$ in the left-hand side of our equation. The result should be **identically** equal to $\frac{1}{10}\sin(\pi x)$.

That means the coefficient of $\cos(\pi x)$ should be $0$, and the coefficient of $\sin(\pi x)$ should be $1$.

That will give you two linear equations in the two unkowns $A$ and $B$. solve.

Answer (score 1):

Find the solution of the homogenous equation (i.e. without right hand side). Hint: exponent.

Find any particular solution. Hint: try sinuses.

Take the sum.

Comment: I know that sin(pi*x) is going to be part of the homogenous solution.  I just forget what I have to make my guess for the particular solution.

Comment: $\sin(\pi x)$ will not be a part of homogenous solution. When you see an ODE with $\sin (bx)$ in the right hand side, it's useful to check whether $p(x)\sin(bx)$ fits as a particular solution $p(x)$ being some polynomial.